# How has this typecasting and displaying been possible?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int *i= (int*)5;
char *p=(char*)'A';
printf("i=%d and p=%c",i,p);
```

I accidentally tried this and I got the output as i=5 and p=A.
Can someone explain? What has happened?

Comment: Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Pointers on your system are the same size as `int`. The `printf()` function itself simply believes that you passed the correct type, and does what the format specifier tells it to do with the values that were passed, which were `5` and `'A'`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not necessarily, got the same result on a 64-bit system with 64-bit pointers and 32-bit ints... Calling convention is different, though, a number of parameters are passed in registers ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane not really int is of 4 bytes and pointer is pf 8 bytes.

Comment: It probably seem to work because of *endianness*.

Comment: @Aconcagua please explain and elaborate, I didn't get it.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari There are different so-called 'calling conventions' that refer to how paramters are passed on from caller to callee and who cleans them up from stack again as well as how the return value is passed – on 32-bit systems e.g. `__cdecl` or `__std_call`. On [64-bit Windows systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170) the first four parameters of a function are passed via designated CPU registers, which, of course, on a 64-bit system comprise 64-bit...

Comment: The point that I was trying to make is that `printf` knows knothing about the types that were passed, only the values. If you say `%d` you *telling* it that the data value is an `int`, whether or not that is actually the case.

Comment: For x86 see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), too (or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for further architectures).

Comment: You might try to compile your application as 32-bit and use types differing in size: `unsigned long long* l = (long long*) 7; printf("%llx %c", l, p)` might – little-endian architecture, cdecl calling convention and top-down stack provided – result in printing `4100000007 A` (the character being included within the long long value). No guarantee for, though, remember: we have undefined behaviour!

Answer (score 3):

Converting from an integer to a pointer might be ok, given that it doesn't cause misalignment (which it does for sure in case of `5`). On some computers, these pointer conversions by themselves might cause a trap/crash. On other computers it will work fine.

Then when you call `printf` with the wrong types, you get undefined behavior. One possible outcome of undefined behavior on some system might be "seems to work just fine". For example if `sizeof(int)` == `sizeof(int*)`, the code might print the result you are getting, although no guarantees.

Regarding passing a `char` to `printf`, `printf` is a variadic function and those functions come with implicit promotion of the passed arguments into the `int` type. Which is why one might get the result `A` too, in case `sizeof(int)` happended to equal `sizeof(char*)`.

And on a system with 64 bit pointers, you might want to try this:

```
printf("size of char* is %zu but the lower 32 bits are %X", sizeof(char*), (unsigned int)p);
```

On a little endian x86 I get the output

```
size of char* is 8 but the lower 32 bits are 41
```

Since the pointer format is little endian, the raw pointer value `41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` can be read as a 32 bit integer `41 00 00 00` to get ASCII `'A'`. So it seems likely that `printf` just peeled off the lowest 32 bits of the pointer.

Silly bonus program for x86 to demonstrate this:

```
int* i  = (int*) (5   | 1145128260ull<<32); // store some secret msg in upper 32 bits
char* p = (char*)('A' | 1178944834ull<<32); // store some secret msg in upper 32 bits

printf("i=%d and p=%c\n",i,p);
printf("%.4s",(char*)&i + 4);
printf("%.4s",(char*)&p + 4);
```

Output:

```
i=5 and p=A
DEADBEEF
```

Comment: could you please try this code in your system and tell me output

Comment: so is there some other way to assign  a character or integer to a pointer of compatible type? I mean without using other variable something like assigning string literal, an anonymous var.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari What do you mean "without using other variable"?

Comment: char *p="Lundin"; Doing this I could assign and access string literal using just a pointers and not other any variable for string. In the same way I wanna get character or integer assigned? At least knowing the fact that in p it is not stored string literal but a pointer to it.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari Still not sure what you are asking, but you could use a compound literal for storing data, then point at it: `int* p = (int[]){ 5 };` And that's the same as declaring an array with 1 item, then pointing at it.